# How to add folders and files in to MSI and how to access that added files in to custom action of MSI

Tags: vb.net, setup-deployment

Actually I want add some folders and files to MSI. Through custom action i want to copy that added folders and files to some destination/target folder.

Any Help please???

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can add Folders as well as Files to MSI but its not using custom action Follow the steps to add Your Folders or Files.

1. Right Click the Project(Setup) in Solution Explorer.
2. Click View > Click FileSystem.
3. New interface will be opened.
4. Right Click on File System on Target Meachine > Click Add Special Folder.
5. You can choose any one of the folder that are listed or go for Custom Folder.
6. Right Click on the Custom Folder you created > Click Add > Click Folder.
7. Right Click on the newly created Folder > click Properties.
8. Set DefaultLocation Property to ("Destination") ie c:.
9. Right Click on the newly created Folder > Click Add > Click File.
10. Browse the file you wants to get added .
11. Build the solution.
12. Your are done.